# Serialize an Collection of Parcelable Objects

Tags: android

My app makes heavy use of a List of Parcelable objects. I want to provide a nice,easy and future proof way of backing up these objects.  Simply serializing the db (which contains all the objects data) seems risky, since it may be hard to restore in future if the db structure changes.

The easiest option, it seems to me, is simply to serialize the collection to a file.  I tried adding Serializable to list of implemented interfaces, but, since I also pass these Objects between Intents using putExtra(), the compiler quite correctly claimed about an ambigious call to putExtra().

Is there any easy way of serializing this collection of Objects, or is there a better solution altogether?

Comment: "Simply serializing the db (which contains all the objects data) seems risky" -- it is precisely as risky as changing the structure of the objects, which would break your serialize files. In either case, you have to write conversion routines to be able to deal with loading in the legacy format (e.g., in the `Serializable`, in `onUpgrade()` of a `SQLiteOpenHelper`). The same holds true for any persistent implementation (XML, JSON, etc.).

Comment: I already have a method which takes a collection of the objects and adds them to the database. It will be easy to manage any changes to the structure - i.e. add null or default values to the db.  If I restore a flat db file and the db structure has changed then it will break. If the structure of the Objects change then the db will as well, so that's safe. It's only restoring legacy dbs that is risky.  As I say, I think I can more easily handle that restoring a collection of object one by one.

Comment: "I already have a method which takes a collection of the objects and adds them to the database." -- then simply back up the database file. Upgrading that will be automatically handled by your `onUpgrade()` of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, should you elect to restore the database file from a backup.

Comment: Will it?  The situation which I am concerned about is something like this: User has the app with db version 1 and performs a backup.  He later upgrades to a version of the app with db version 2, but, since he has not added any items does not perform a new backup. Db version 2 has added a column and removed a redundant one. onUpgrade() means that the app continues to work despite the data originating with a legacy db. He then gets a new phone and installs the new app.  He uses the app and adds some new data before then using the backup file to restore the old data from his previous...

Comment: ... phone. Would restoring from a db file backup not overwrite the new data?  Will the difference in db structure not break the app when he attempts to restore the backup?

Comment: "Would restoring from a db file backup not overwrite the new data?" -- that depends on how you do it. If you overwrite the file, you overwrite the data. If you instead use your `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open the backup copy and another copy of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open the master, you can do whatever you want to transfer over the data. "Will the difference in db structure not break the app when he attempts to restore the backup?" -- no, because the metadata in the backup would say it is a v1 schema, and your `onUpgrade()` would be called.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a closer look at that class and see if it's a solution for me.

Comment: How can I use the SQLiteOpenHelper to open the backup database? I can only see how to open a db from the /data directory.

Comment: IIRC, the `name` parameter accepts a path nowadays, though it did not used to, at least in the 1.x timeframe.